# Verification of composite function

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory

If $f : (0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ such that $f \circ g = I_\mathbb{R}$ where $I_\mathbb{R}$ is the identity function.

Wouldn't a perfect example of this be if $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ thus $f \circ g = x$ as required?

Comment: Wait, no because when x = 0 it is not in the domain of g which is all real numbers

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you have seen the problem. It would work if you wanted both functions to map $(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$. But $f(x)=\log_a x$ and $g(x)=a^x$ do the trick.

Comment: gahhh, yes you're right. should have thought of that. Thank you

Comment: Just in case you are looking for an example that works: $f(x)=\ln(x), g(x)=e^x$. ;-)

Comment: Another: $f(x) = x-1/x$, and $g(x) = x/2 + \sqrt{(x/2)^2 + 1}$

Comment: @maxmilgram : Your example is a special case of mine (take $a=e$)

Answer (score 0):

$f \circ g = I_\mathbb{R}$ for any two functions where $f^{-1}(x)=g(x)$, or vice versa, by definition of the inverse function. Also, as $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are inverse functions, $f \circ g =g\circ f$. Of course, the domain of $f \circ g$ is defined as the intersection of the sets of the codomain of $g(x)$ and the domain of $f(x)$. The domain of $g \circ f$ is the intersection of the codomain of $f(x)$ and the domain of $g(x)$. The domain of $y=x$ is $ \mathbb{R}$, so we need the domain of $f \circ g $ or $g \circ f$ to be the same. Notice too that the codomain of $g(x)$ is the same as the domain of $f(x)$, and the domain of $g(x)$ is the same as the codomain of $f(x)$. Thus, as long as at least one of the 4 domains and codomains is $\mathbb{R}$, that means that either $f \circ g$ or $ g \circ f$ has a domain of $\mathbb{R}$, and thus is equal to $I_\mathbb{R}$. Unfortunately, because neither the domain or codomain of $\frac{1}{x}$ is equal to $\mathbb{R}$, your example does not quite work.

Comment: Well, no: saying that $f\circ g$ is the identity implies neither that $f$ and $g$ are invertible nor that $g\circ f$ is the identity (on $(0,\infty)$, in this case).

Comment: Well, it's true that any given function may not be invertible, however, my understanding is that if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are inverses, their composition always produces $y=x$, albeit with some domain restrictions. I understand that $\circ g=x$ does not necessarily mean that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are inverses, but if given that they are inverses, they would satisfy that.

Comment: Let $g\colon\mathbb{R}\to(0,\infty)$ be an injective map, but not surjective. Let $f\colon(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined to yield $f(y)=x$ whenever $g(x)=y$ and $f(y)=42$ for every $y$ not in the image of $g$. Then $f\circ g$ is the identity on $\mathbb{R}$, but $f$ is definitely not invertible.

Comment: I'm aware that $f \circ g=I_\mathbb{R}$ does not imply the two functions are necessarily inverses.